# Cakephp production application on subdomain in Single EC2 instance

Tags: apache, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have a cakephp web app which I've uploaded and linked to an apache server on an ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance. I now wish to:

a. link the production version with my domain under a subdomain link like: subdomain1.mywebsite.com
b. Link the development version on subdomain2.mywebsite.com so I can keep making changes here and pushing them to the production subdomain.

Do I have to use virtual hosts in apache, or is there another way using cakephp only?

Comment: You would probably use virtual hosts provided that your dev code and production code are on the same instance. Its generally not a good idea to do development on the same instances as you are running production code. You run the risk of breaking your production code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using virtual hosts, it will make everything much easier.

Although I don't think you run any real risk of breaking your production code as production and development virtual hosts will normally be completely isolated (the code will lie in different folders), what you risk affecting is performance or stability of the production server, either by consuming too much resources (running tests or going on an endless loop) or causing severe DB damage that will require a DB server stop. You are also limited on the things you can try (like installing php mods, versions etc).

Thus I would recommend for small projects to develop locally (or wherever else like another EC2 instance) and do staging tests on a virtualhost of the production server.

This will be extremely easier if you adopt a DVCN like git with a good workflow and use cake's DB migrations.